# How do I add a button to a td using js and set multiple attr?

Tags: javascript, firebase

My code is this, but attr delete botton, not work

```
var newList = snapshot.val();

var tableList = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
var rowIndex = 1;
var row = tableList.insertRow(rowIndex);

var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
var cellBottonDelete = row.insertCell(1); 

cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newList.name));
cellBottonDelete.appendChild(document.createElement("input", { type: "button", value:"Delete"}));

rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
```

input is created but attr not. Any idea?

Comment: `type: "buttom"` should be `"button"` for starters.

Comment: You need to use setAttribute

Comment: Sorry, its my error, but in original code is "button" . Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the solution

```
var newList = snapshot.val();
var tableList = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
var rowIndex = 1;
var row = tableList.insertRow(rowIndex);
var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
var cellBottonDelete = row.insertCell(1); 

var itd = document.createElement('input');
itd.setAttribute("type","button");
itd.setAttribute("value","Delete");

cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newList.name));
cellBottonDelete.appendChild(itd);

rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
```